# Preprocessing and dropout in Autoencoders?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am working with autoencoders and have few confusions, I am trying different autoencoders like :

```
fully_connected autoencoder
convolutional autoencoder
denoising autoencoder
```

I have two dataset , One is numerical dataset which have float and int values , Second is text dataset which have text and date values :

Numerical dataset looks like:

```
date ,        id ,             check_in , check_out , coke_per , permanent_values , temp
13/9/2017     142453390001    134.2       43.1        13         87                 21
14/9/2017     142453390005    132.2       46.1        19         32                 41
15/9/2017     142453390002    120.2       42.1        33         99                 54
16/9/2017     142453390004    100.2       41.1        17         39  

           89
```

Any my text dataset looks like :

```
data              text
13/9/2017         i totally understand this conversation about farmer market and the organic products, a nice conversation ’cause prices are cheaper than traditional
14/9/2017         The conversation was really great. But I think I need much more practice. I need to improve my listening a lot. Now I’m very worried because I thought that I’d understand more. Although, I understood but I had to repeat and repeat. See you!!!
```

So my questions are:

Should i normalize my numerical data values before feeding to any type of autoencoder? if they are int and float values still i have to normalize?

Which activation function should i use in autoencoder? Some article and research paper says , "sigmoid" and some says "relu" ?

Should i use dropout in each layer ? like if my artichare for autoencoder looks like

```
encoder (1000 --> 500 -- > 256 ----> 128 ) --> decoder (128 --> 256 --> 500--> 784)
```

something like this?

```
encoder(dropout(1000,500) --> dropout( 500,256) --> dropout (256,128) )----> decoder(dropout(128,256),dropout(256,500),dropout(500,784))
```

For text dataset , If i am using word2vec or any embedding to convert text into vector then i would have float values for each word , should i normalize that data too ?

```
text ( Hello How are you  ) -- > word2vec(text) ----> ([1854.92002 , 54112.89774 ,5432.9923 ,5323.98393])
```

should i normalize this values or directly use in autoencoder ?

Answer (score 0):

**Normalisation** is done when the data from different features are from different scales. Here Check_out and Check_in are at very different scales from coke_per. Another possible reason for Normalisation is helpful is that when normalized the data is well behaved to learning algorithms. If you do not do normalization there is a chance of non-convergence of your learning algorithm.

**Dropout** Can be thought of a regularizer for your dataset. Hence it is preferred to include Dropout for the Bias/Variance issue. You could also include BatchNorm Layer if you like. I like to think of Dropout as model averaging.

**SoftMax/Relu** Generally Relu's are preferred since vanishing gradient issue crops up with softmax activations. But it actually depends on the problem. I would start by using Relu and replace with softmax if metric that I am testing on is not giving good results.

Comment: After normalization of data and feeding to the autoencoder , then getting output from autoencoder should i Denormalization data or use same values ?

Comment: On the output of the encoder have a activation function that ouputs the same normalized range as input: tanh for [-1 to 1] or sigmoid [0 to 1].